# material-ui: why is the code running twice?

Tags: material-ui

can someone explain to me why the following code is executed twice? (See image)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

import raw from "./testfile.csv";



function ReadFile(file) {
    fetch(raw)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(text => {
            console.log('text decoded:', text);
        });
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
            <Box sx={{ my: 4 }}>
                <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
                    Create React App example
                </Typography>
                <ReadFile />

            </Box>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

[executed twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhDNT.png)

I don't understand why the code is executed 2x by the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have <React.StrictMode> in index.js? It already happened to me that my code executed twice because of that.